# ユーザープロファイルの「行動履歴」にデザインバグ

Tags: バグ, 完了, デザイン

[ユーザープロファイルの「行動履歴」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/30/ento?tab=activity&sort=all)に色々なバグが発見しました。

> **すべて** - 日付がおかしいです：「月」と「日」が書いてされない。
> [image: all]
>
> **承認** - テキストが縦書きです。
> [image: accepted]
>
> **投稿数** - テキストが縦書きで、英語が残っている。
> [image: posts]
>
> **バッジ** - テキストが縦書きです。
> [image: badge]
>
> **コメント** - テキストが縦書きです。
> [image: comment]
>
> **編集** - テキストが縦書きです。（先よりまだ大丈夫と思うけど・・・）
> [image: edit]
>
> **レビュー** - 大丈夫だと思って、テキストがまだ翻訳されてない。
> [image: review]
>
> **推奨** - テキストが縦書きで、英語が残っている。
> [image: suggested]

Comment: 縦書きになってる箇所ですが、幅指定されてないんですね。英語だと単語内で折り返されないので問題ないようですが、日本語だと `white-space: nowrap` を指定するとよいでしょうか。